# Codename one IOS App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, codenameone

We have successfully tested our IOS app on IPAD with Codename one Build IOS debug feature. It is working fine out here. But When we build for the App Store, The app downloads in the device and don't get installed. We have already generated the certificates for production and development, yet we didn't found any perfect solution

Comment: if you are using a development certificate to build ipa of your app then your devices UDID need to be there in your development certificate.

if you are using production certificate then no need to add device UDID's.

Comment: We have a development certificate and a production certificate both. still debug app is able to be run over the testing device while on the same device, the app store build app is not able to get installed. And I am unable to understand this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

App store build can't work on a device until it's signed by Apple. It's meant for publishing in the store. The only app that could work on your device without passing through App store is a debug app.

When your app is fully ready, you can submit it by going to [itunes connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) -> My Apps and click on the plus sign to create a new app. Follow the process and submit all the requirements.

To upload the App store IPA file, open **Application Loader** on your Mac, login and Upload your file. It will appear on your iTunes connect within few minutes.

It takes approximately 7 working days (9 days) for Apple to review and approve or reject your app, so relax and be patient.

Comment: Its an application to be used within our organisation. Hence, we are planning to host the ipa file with App Store Build (codename one) on our own website. Would this require the app to be published to app store or we can do it with other way to fulfill the requirements as stated ?